# onClick event is not triggered for custom component in xml layout android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I am trying to handle the onClick event for custom view component, but still not working,

Here's my custom view layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/followButtonRView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/followSourceButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/droidkufi_bold"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="@string/followSourceButton"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/followButtonProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
```

Although attribute **Android: clickable = True**, still not working

Below is the code block of using the above custom view

```
<today.akhbarna.news.ui.custom.FollowSourceButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        setFollowState="@{source.selected}"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="@{(view) ->sourceListeners.onClick(view,source.sourceId,SourceClickTypes.FollowSource)}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

FollowSourceButton source code

```
class FollowSourceButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs) {

private var btn: TextView;
private var progressBar:   ProgressBar
private var relativeLayout : RelativeLayout

init {
    inflate(context,R.layout.follow_source_button,this)
    btn = findViewById(R.id.followSourceButton)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.followButtonProgress)
    relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.followButtonRView)
    isClickable = true
}
```

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Have you properly initialised `sourceListeners` to your layout?

Comment: Definitely, I am using the same in different areas and it's working probably
If I switch the custom view "today.akhbarna.news.ui.custom.FollowSourceButton" with a normal button it will work

Comment: Does your FollowSourceButton extend a button class? Another way could be to set an 'on touch' listener and see if that works

Comment: No, it extends RelativeLayout,

I will add the source code above

Comment: The `<RelativeLayout>` in the internal layout is redundant. Your custom `View` _is_ the `RelativeLayout`. Change those to `<merge>` tags instead.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, It does work after replacing relative layout with a merge tag